Fetching ordered relationship with many times in Core Data is very slow
I have Library and Books entities where one library can contain many books where the relationship is an inherently ordered one in my app since the user can store the books in whatever order they want in a library.
When I access the relationship to get about 50k books from a library entity to store in an array, it takes so long (i.e. almost 2 to 3 second blocking the main thread) compared to using a FetchRequest using some kind of sort such as by name of the book.
Is there a solution to this problem (i.e. such as using some kind of async fetch request) or is it better to have an order attribute for the Book to be able to use a fetch request instead but updating the order attribute of 50k books would be a nightmare and would be very inefficient when the user reorders the order of the books within the library. (I assume a fetch request is faster since it would not fault in all 50k books into memory?)
The issue is I want to use a fetch request but the relationship being an ordered one means I have no way to sort the books of the library efficiently such as using a FRC or sth like that.
extension Library {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest< Library > {
        return NSFetchRequest<Library>(entityName: "Library")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var books: NSOrderedSet?
    
    public var booksArray: [Book] {
        books?.array as? [Book] ?? []
    }
}

extension Book {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Book> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Book>(entityName: "Book")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var library: Library?

    public var wrappedId: UUID {
        id ?? UUID()
    }
    
    public var wrappedName: Date {
        name ?? "Unknown Book"
    }
}

class LibraryDetailViewManager: NSObject {
    
    var selectedSort: BooksSort = .name
    var books = [Book]()
        
    func setup(using sort: BooksSort, for library: Library) {
        selectedSort = sort
        
        let fetchRequest = Books.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "library == %@", library)
        
        if sort == .name {
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Book.name, ascending: true)]
            books = try! moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } else {
            //This line to access the 50k books is very very slow. Blocks the main thread for almost 3 seconds.
            self.books = library.booksArray
        }
    }
}


What are you really trying to do? Can you pass a Library to LibraryDetailViewManager? Given a Library instance library, does library.object(at:index) give you what you need? You're right, instantiating all 50k of those Books is going to take some time.
